# How to choose records, which appear in grid form in Dynamics AX

Tags: axapta, record, microsoft-dynamics, x++

I would like to display in grid in Form only few records from Datasource. Should I create method in grid or in datasource in Form?
For example select * from ... where Name=="John" ?

Comment: Modify your data source query after super of data source init method.

Comment: Refer http://www.axaptapedia.com/Datasource_Query_Manipulation

Answer (score 1):

If the criteria you'd like to use is where Name == "John", you could add a range to the formDataSource in it's init/executeQuery methods.

Something like this: MyTable_DS.addRange(FieldNum(MyTable,MyField)).value("John");